# What is the last version of pgAdmin to support PostgreSQL 9.*?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I have browsed and searched many of the release notes here:
https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/release_notes.html

The release notes for version 6.13 onward list these major versions as the "Supported Database Servers": PostgreSQL: 10, 11, 12, 13 and 14

But can't find any mention of when support for major versions less than 10 were dropped. I know it is no longer officially supported, but there are several databases I use out there still on 9.6 and I am at the mercy of their maintainers.

I am currently running pgAdmin 6.14 and I get the following warning when I connect to these older databases:

> You have connected to a server version that is older than
> is supported by pgAdmin. This may cause pgAdmin to break in strange
> and unpredictable ways. Or a plague of frogs. Either way, you have been warned

Some things work, but I cannot list the tables on any Postgres 9.6 database.

Comment: There is no version "Postgres 9", there is 9.0, 9.1, 9.2, 9.3, 9.4, 9.5 and 9.6 - and all of them are no longer maintained.

Comment: You can use psql for that specific version.

Comment: Thanks, I am looking for notes about when they dropped any major version below 10. They list the supported versions as just 10, 11, 12, etc. So I just referenced 9 that way as well.

Comment: Google Cloud SQL still officially supports version 9.6 - https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/db-versions. I found that pgAdmin 4 version 6.12 is working fine with the 9.6 release - https://pgadmin-archive.postgresql.org/pgadmin4/v6.12/index.html

Answer (score -1):

PgAdmin 4 v6.12 works with PostGreSQL 9.*
I could list tables with no errors. (Tested on PostGreSQL 9.2.24)

Comment: If I try this with our server, I get a an error message like "wait_event_type does not exist LINE 10." I cannot get a list of tables.